# How to set properties of new TabPage pages at TabControl?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, tabcontrol

When new **TabControl** is placed in designer, it comes with two default **TabPage** pages:

[image]

I can easily inherit and modify **TabControl** itself, but
**how can I intercept creation of tab pages and set their properties?**

- For example I need **`UseVisualStyleBackColor = false`** by default for every **TabPage**.

*(C# or VB – whatever you prefer.)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could handle the `ControlAdded` event and test the Control that was added and work on it accordingly:

```
  Private Sub TabControl1_ControlAdded(sender As Object, e As ControlEventArgs) Handles TabControl1.ControlAdded
    Debug.WriteLine("Something added: " & e.Control.Name & " " & e.Control.GetType().ToString)

   If TypeOf e.Control Is TabPage Then
      Dim tp As TabPage = CType(e.Control, TabPage)
      tp.UseVisualStyleBackColor = False
    End If
  End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Dennis. I have updated my answer for a more robust test

Answer (score 1):

Inherit TabControl and Override [OnControlAdded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.oncontroladded?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) method.

```
class MyTabControl : TabControl
{
    protected override void OnControlAdded(ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnControlAdded(e);

        var page = e.Control as TabPage;
        if (page != null)
        {
            page.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            page.BackColor = Color.Red;

        }
    }
}
```

This way, if you add TabPage using code or using designer, your  settings will applied.

In this case, Inheritance works better that event handling, because there is no need to handle ControlAdded event on every form you have in project.

Comment: Also very helpful, thank you. @joehanna was first with key idea, so I'll award his answer.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, I was testing the solution when he posted his good answer. Anyway, It will be helpful to others to consider Inheritance too :)

Comment: Yes, definitely. I appreciate your answer, +1, it is great and has clean code. (Check my answer for final implementation.)

Answer (score 1):

For convenience of others, I'm sharing what I finally implemented.

**Credits** go to [@joehanna](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32327193/2392157) for idea and [@Reza Aghaei](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32327240/2392157) for clean code. So my solution is based on their contributions:

```vb
Public Class TabBasedMultipage : Inherits TabControl

    Protected Overrides Sub OnControlAdded(e As ControlEventArgs)

        MyBase.OnControlAdded(e)

        Dim tabPage As TabPage = TryCast(e.Control, TabPage)
        If tabPage IsNot Nothing Then
            tabPage.UseVisualStyleBackColor = False
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thank you, and a +1 for your fast and accurate answer and your kindness :)